# Create a map of Canada and USA with Datamaps in a single page

Tags: datamaps

I am using [Datamaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) to create a map of Canada and USA. I saw the tutorial and/or examples in its website and I saw a "USA map only" example. And I did that:

```
    <script>
        var addUSA = new Datamap({
            scope: 'usa',
            element: document.getElementById('usa-map'),
            geographyConfig: {
                highlightOnHover: false,
                borderColor: '#006298',
                borderWidth: 0.8,
                popupTemplate: function(geography, data) {
                    return "<div class='hoverinfo'><strong>" + data.info + "</strong></div>";
                }
            },
            dataUrl: 'data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {},
            fills: {
                defaultFill: '#FFFFFF'
            }
        });
        addUSA.labels();
    </script>
```

So I assume that you can also create a "Canada map only". But the problem is, I don't know how to combine two countries.

I aim for labels, the hover-info and json that's why I'm using Datamaps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I've found this URL entitled Custom Map Data in Datamaps by Mark DiMarco and I used and tried copying what he had done. On that link, he created a map of Afghanistan which was not included in his main examples on Datamaps website. But instead of one country, we will combine two countries custom map using Datamaps. This is an experiment I've made but I hope this will be the answer to your problem

First, he created a custom topo json for Afghanistan. He published a tutorial on how to create custom map data but I think I don't have an access 'cause I'm getting 404 or he took it down. Going back, the code he used for that custom topo json can also be found in his other works located at "More Versions" link in Datamaps website. You just need to look for the country/ies you need to make a custom topo json. On your end, look for datamaps.afg.js and datamaps.usa.js; and get the json.

I only have 1 reputation and I am limit with two URLs. Just visit this [GitHub](https://github.com/ReiAyame/Combining-Two-Countries-in-Datamaps) site where I put those two custom topo json for Canada and USA.

---

*HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Canada and USA</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgithub.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/master/dist/datamaps.none.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- CANADA -->
    <h1>CANADA</h1>
    <div id="canada"></div>
    <!-- USA -->
    <h1>USA</h1>
    <div id="usa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

*CSS*

```
#canada {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 450px;
    width: 400px;
}

#usa {
    border: 2px solid #EDA552;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

---

*JQUERY*

```
$(function() {
    var canadaMap = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('canada'),
        geographyConfig: {
            dataUrl: 'canada.topo.json'
        },
        scope: 'canada',
        fills: {
            defaultFill: '#bada55'
        },
        setProjection: function(element) {
            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .center([-95, 71])
                .scale(200)
                .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
            var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
            return {path: path, projection: projection};
        }
    });
    var USAmap = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('usa'),
        geographyConfig: {
            dataUrl: 'usa.topo.json'
        },
        scope: 'usa',
        fills: {
            defaultFill: '#bada55'
        },
        setProjection: function(element) {
            var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                .center([-120, 54])
                .scale(250)
                .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2, element.offsetHeight / 2]);
            var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
            return {path: path, projection: projection};
        }
    });
});
```

---

Working code here => [**JS FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/yumicchi/ayr13s4b/)

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much. This is just what I really needed. I'll just edit the design. Thanks mate!

Comment: How do you determinate the center and scale of the projection? according to the json Topography?

Comment: To be honest, I'm still studying D3 >.< center([x,y]) lets you locate your map at where you wish to and scale() lets you zoom in and out thy map. I think Datamaps use D3 for getting the projection.